# Does change of futures price influence spot price to change as well?

Tags: finance, futures, forward

- There is no problem in understanding how the changes in spot price can cause the future price to change. For example, if we have a big changes in supply and demand (e.g. war breakout, unexpected heavy rainfall, etc), the spot market would be affected the first. It results in the changes of spot price of commodity or equity, and then it would ends up influencing the future price to change as well.
- It is described in the following formula, which shows how the theoretical price of futures is decided. So when I learned this formula show below, I thought it was the **spot price** that drives the change of futures price (spot price -> futures price).

[image]

- However, can the **change of futures price drive the change of spot price as well?** For example, if many speculators bet on the long position of futures, would the spot price go up as well?
- If it is possible, what is the name of the theory that justifies this relationship (futures price -> spot price)? Can you provide me with any blog article or analyst report that I can study, please?

Comment: Theoretically atleast, arbitrage should make that relationship that you wrote hold no matter whether spot or futures move. Of course, In practice, there maybe be some opportunities for arbitrage ( index arbitrage for example ) but they won't be frequent or consistent.

Comment: @markleeds I know what you meant by "theoretically", but what I am looking for is at least an anecdotal evidence, which makes it seem possible that change of futures price can cause the spot price to change as well

Comment: Did you [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=impact+of+futures+market+on+spot&client=ms-android-google&sxsrf=AOaemvIMq1QZviKVm4QDDZ_X7DwNf3N-aQ%3A1633213532693&ei=XNxYYZnYKemN9u8Pzd-giAY&oq=impact+of+futures+market+on+spot&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAM6BAgjECc6BAghEBVQ9hZYkhhgqxloAHAAeACAAYQBiAG7ApIBAzEuMpgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by anecdotal ? If the futures price changes and the spot doesn't change right away, then activity will occur that will either A) push the futures price back to where it was or B) eventually bring the spot price to a place where there is no possibility for arbitrage or C) some combination of both A) and B).

Comment: For some products, price discovery is concentrated in futures rather than spot. Seems reasonable that for those, futures would 'drive the change of spot' rather than the other way around.